# JAX-RS dependency injection

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, jersey, jax-rs

I've done projects using Spring Rest. Now we have a small rest project and planning to do with Jersey JAX-RS. I'm new to this and referred SO and other blogs to successfully implement a Rest api with dependency injection.

Have following code.

**AppConfig.java**

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/")
public class AppConfig extends Application {    
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        System.out.println("AppConfig");
        final Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        s.add(Controller.class);
        s.add(AppFeature.class);
        return s;
    }
}
```

**AppBinder.java**

```
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;

public class AppBinder extends AbstractBinder {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        System.out.println("AppBinder");
        bind(ReflectionService.class).to(ReflectionService.class);
    }
}
```

**AppFeature.java**

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Feature;
import javax.ws.rs.core.FeatureContext;

public class AppFeature implements Feature {
    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
        System.out.println("AppFeature");
        context.register(new AppBinder());
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Controller.java**

```
@Path("/")
public class Controller {   
    @Inject
    Service service;    
    public Controller(){
        System.out.println("Controller created");
    }
    // other methods
}
```

**Service.java**

```
@Singleton
public class Service    
    public Service(){
        System.out.println("Service instance created");
    }
    // other methods
}
```

I assume that each instance of Controller and Service is created on **Tomcat 8** server startup and dependency injection is done. But during startup, got this on console

> INFO: Registering the Jersey servlet application, named
>   com.sample.auto2.AppConfig, at the servlet mapping /*, with the
>   Application class of the same name.
>
> AppConfig
>
> AppConfig
>
> Nov 15, 2016 12:22:20 PM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler initialize
>   INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.6 2014-02-18
>   21:52:53...
>
> AppFeature
>
> AppBinder
>
> Nov 15, 2016 12:22:21 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory

**Each time**, we send a request, got following in console

> Service instance created
>
> Controller created

My Questions

1. Service,Controller constructors is being called whenever we send an
   http request; does it create instances in each request or just
   calling constructor?
2. Why System.out in *AppConfig* is called twice?
3. Is there a better way for setting up my small project, which does not have any db access and only three post endpoints?

**EDIT:**

As per the links provided by @Harikrishnan, added `@Singleton` for `Controller` class. Now the constructors called only once (**at the very first request** - Why not during server startup!!).

But why Service class constructor called on each request (earlier before adding @Singleton to Controller), even if its singleton? Also the other problems remain.

**EDIT 2**:

Thanks @peeskillet. So these are the results for me.

1. This called constructors only once at very first request

   ```
   bind(ReflectionService.class).to(ReflectionService.class).in(Singleton.class);
   bind(Controller.class).to(Controller.class).in(Singleton.class);
   ```
2. This give the error on http request

   ```
   bind(ReflectionService.class).to(ReflectionService.class).in(Immediate.class);

   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find an active context for org.glassfish.hk2.api.Immediate
   ```

   But it's ok, because
3. This called constructor on server startup and only once

   ```
   bind(new ReflectionService()).to(ReflectionService.class);
   bind(new Controller()).to(Controller.class);
   ```
4. By this, injection done on startup, but 404 error on http request. (Thought Controller is configured in AppBinder, then why in AppConfig)

   ```
   @ApplicationPath("/")
   public class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig  {    
       public AppConfig() {
           register(new AppBinder());
       }
   }
   ```
5. And this make it run, as you said!

   ```
   @ApplicationPath("/")
   public class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig  {        
       public AppConfig() {
           register(new AppBinder());
           register(Controller.class);
       }
   }
   ```

FINALLY THESE ARE ALL I NEEDED

```
public class AppBinder extends AbstractBinder {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(new ReflectionService()).to(ReflectionService.class);
        bind(new Controller()).to(Controller.class);
    }
}

@ApplicationPath("/")
public class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig  {    
    public AppConfig() {
        register(new AppBinder());
        register(Controller.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Service,Controller constructors is being called whenever we send an http request; does it create instances in each request or just calling constructor?

Unfortunately, the `@Singleton` doesn't have any effect when binding using the `AbstractBinder`. We need to explicitly say it should be a singleton

```
bind(ReflectionService.class).to(ReflectionService.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

The default behavior is a "per lookup" scope, which means that a new instance is created every time the service is requested

> (at the very first request - Why not during server startup!!)

This is how it works. There is also an `ImmediateScope`, which will cause it to be created on startup

```
 bind(ReflectionService.class).to(ReflectionService.class).in(ImmediateScope.class)
```

Or you can just use an instance instead of class, and it will automatically be a singleton

```
bind(new ReflectionService()).to(ReflectionService.class)
```

> Service,Controller constructors is being called whenever we send an http request; does it create instances in each request or just calling constructor?

This is the default behavior. A new instance of the resource class for each request. As mentioned, if you only want once instance, then mark it as a `@Singleton`

> Why System.out in AppConfig is called twice?

Not sure, probably just required for Jersey internal processing on bootstrap

> Is there a better way for setting up my small project, which does not have any db access and only three post endpoints?

Your set up is fine, but if you are using Jersey then you should use the `ResourceConfig` (extension of `Application`) class instead of `Application`

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public AppConfig() {
        register(new AppBinder());
        register(Controller.class);
    }
}
```

With this, you don't need to wrap the `AppBinder` in the `AppFeature`. Jersey already knows how to process the `AppBinder`

Comment: Thanks @peeskillet. That was very helpful. I would like to mark my observations too. Cant comment, as its too long. So editing your answer

Comment: I just edited your post instead of adding it to mine. Oh and for the Immediate scope. I forget you also need to configure [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28123656/2587435). Also you don't need to add the controller to the binder

Comment: Removing controller from binder creates its object on each request without `@Singleton`.  Then adding `@Singleton` creates it only once on first request. But i need it during server startup, and worked with adding controller to binder. Is there any issue for that?

Comment: See the link in my comment

Comment: You could also use `register(new Controller())`

Comment: But really, if you want, you could simply just do `register(new Controller(new Service())` and forget the binder. No injection needed

Comment: Ok @peeskillet. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default Jersey creates a new instance of the resource class for every request. So if you don't annotate the Jersey resource class, it implicitly uses @RequestScoped scope

Please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/20505899/721597

Also look at [Jersey 2 singleton dependency injection creates multiple instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192309/jersey-2-singleton-dependency-injection-creates-multiple-instances)